# Can't use a property of a StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

The object `DeckOfCards` has a `dealout` method which gets a list of Players `List<?Player>` as a parameter. I want to execute the `dealout` method after pressing the Elevated Button. Why can't I use `listOfPlayers` from `Gambling Table`?

```
import 'package:card_game/app/home/player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'deck_of_cards.dart';

class GamblingTable extends StatefulWidget {
  GamblingTable({Key? key, this.player}) : super(key: key);
  final Player? player;

  static Player? player2 = Player('opponent');
  static DeckOfCards deckOfCards = const DeckOfCards();

  late List<Player?> ?listOfPlayers = [player, player2];


  @override
  State<GamblingTable> createState() => _GamblingTableState();
}

class _GamblingTableState extends State<GamblingTable> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              GamblingTable.deckOfCards.dealOut(GamingTable.?listOfPlayers);
            },
            child: const Text('dealout'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to use “GamblingTable.” to access stateful widget properties . Just use “widget.propertyName” and that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You can add variables in the state class directly. Use widget.variablename to access the passed variables

```dart
class GamblingTable extends StatefulWidget {
  GamblingTable({Key? key, this.player}) : super(key: key);
  final Player? player;


  @override
  State<GamblingTable> createState() => _GamblingTableState();
}

class _GamblingTableState extends State<GamblingTable> {
Player? player2 = Player('opponent');
late List<Player?>? listOfPlayers = [widget.player, player2];

DeckOfCards deckOfCards = DeckOfCards();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              deckOfCards.dealOut(listOfPlayers);
            },
            child: const Text('dealout'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
   );
  }
}
```